# Alternative to creating a form in Access for users to associate two datasets

Tags: vba, ms-access, foreign-keys, workflow

I am repeatedly finding the need to create an interface to facilitate a workflow for users to pair two sets of data. The simplest example I can come up with is assigning baseball players to positions. Imagine two tables: one with players' names and other relevant stats, and the other with positions to be filled on the team (pitcher, catcher, short stop, etc.).

To do this in the past, I've developed Access forms with two lists side-by-side (players on the left, positions on the right) and some VBA-backed buttons that populate a table tracking assigned associations (i.e. when Babe Ruth is assigned to Short Stop a third table is populated with two foreign keys to link the entries). I usually add some filters to the form and sometimes add a tracked history of changes to make it easier to use.

I have done this enough times that I've started to think there must be a better approach. My question is: Is there a name for this type of workflow and are there any tools or ready-made solutions to simplify the use-case of asking users to create relationships between two data sets?

Comment: Sounds like you're modelling a many-to-many relationship, i.e. joining two unrelated tables by their compounded primary keys (i.e. `Player.Id`, `Position.Id` => `(PlayerId,PositionId)`). User needs a way to pick a player and a position, and a form seems a pretty solid way to do this. What's the problem?

Comment: Make your form unbound and parameterize everything about it, and then you only need one form to maintain any many-to-many junction table.

Comment: If VBA in Access is the most efficient way to model this workflow then there is no problem. I'm hoping this is a common-enough workflow that someone has matured a tool set to address it so I'm not writing these from scratch (though, with re-use, where applicable). Scale is becoming a concern but was not a constraint in the original question. Maybe writing custom web UI and SQL back end is the solution but it seems like a lot of work for what is probably a very common problem?

Comment: The more common problem would be a one-to-many relationship, where a form would show some dropdown field and the user gets to pick the FK. Many-to-many relationships are relatively common, but several orders of magnitude less than 1:many. Many-to-Many works with a junction table that may or may not carry additional metadata - if that's a common scenario for your project, make a general-purpose, reusable/scalable solution for your project. Note that this site isn't very warm about questions asking for off-site tools, tutorials, and other resources. See [ask]

Comment: Knew I was taking a chance asking this way. Thanks for the replies, anyway.